# Truncate particular tag

Tags: php

I used the below snipet to restrict the text in $body variable, this works fine.But in $body there is `<span>` tag before starting of the text. How can I truncate this tag?The text in $body is something like this:

```
<span>heading</span>
text I want to display
```

Below is the snipet to restrict text.

```
$out = strlen($body[0]['value']) > 50 ? substr($body[0]['value'],0,50)."..." : $body[0]['value'];
print $out;
```